# This opinion-based question must be closed

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The question [What must someone know in statistics and machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402333/must-know-in-statistics-and-machine-learning) is not suitable for the stats.SE format because it is primarily opinion-based. I believe that much is obvious on its face.

OP's appeal to make this question an exception is premised on a misunderstanding of how this site works. The help center outlines how to ask good questions, and the closure message explains why the question was originally closed.

Making the question community wiki is not a remedy for off-topic content. If it were, we would simply change all off-topic questions to CW; the fact that we do not, but explicitly close them and have robots eventually delete them, suggests that we believe hosting a large volume of off-topic content which continues to attract traffic does active harm to the website. Likewise, community-wiki questions must still be on-topic: [Must a community wiki post follow the pattern of a Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258006/must-a-community-wiki-post-follow-the-pattern-of-a-qa)

Comment: CW is not used to "remedy" clearly off-topic content on [stats.SE]. It is *sometimes* used for borderline 'big-list / subjective' threads that do seem to hold a lot of value that would otherwise be lost.  It's not clear to me that that will be the case here, but it might.  In that sense, the CW status may be a workable compromise.  (Alternatively, if it doesn't seem to have great value in that sense, we can close, lock, & even possibly delete the thread.)  I'm inclined to let it play out for a bit as CW to see if it becomes especially informative / valuable, and revisit its status then.

Comment: I personally would close such questions, but since it's a borderline, I let the community decide. As far as the number of such questions is small, I see no harm is leaving some of them (same applies to other borderline questions as well).

Comment: I personally find it is offensive to call it "flattery". As I wrote this actually is the best website I know. I even asked if you can suggest another one where I can post the question which was not really the case in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you've made this argument several times but have ignored the replies. Not knowing where to post a question doesn't make it on-topic at stats.SE. I've already suggested that reddit favors free-wheeling discussions, but you can also try Twitter or Quora. Your question is, essentially, "What is important to know in statistics and machine learning?" You don't have to post it as a question to find the answer! The best way to start learning is by reading prominent books in the field. We even have a tag for `[references]` on the main site. You can also look at popular tags for suggested topics.

Comment: If this had not already gone to discussion here, I would have closed the question without a moment of hesitation - I see it as nearly a canonical example of an overly broad ("big list") question with no correct answers (there's too little context to call any one answer correct), just a load of opinions. It should be closed. Moreover, half the question is clearly off topic (it's meta discussion). It's a good *discussion* topic but this is not a site for discussion topics, such questions belong elsewhere (I think it would be fine on chat though and it would fit reddit's /r/statistics quite well)

Comment: I agree with the arguments to close it and so have voted to close.

Comment: Agreed. I've voted to close this and also the cartoon thread that inevitably gets brought up as a defence for these cases.

Comment: This meta question by now has 9 upvotes and 1 downvote after one day. I personally would say that this is about as close to a consensus as we will ever get. Can we close the question now before it hits the Hot Network Questions list? (Or won't it because it's CW?)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: It did hit the HNQ list; I removed it.

Answer (score 9):

The question is very broad and may be considered a [bad subjective question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). The way that the question is phrased suggests this very clearly.

> What do you consider a person must....?

This makes it more like an opinion poll. (it is not only subjective, but also unclear and broad, for instance what scope does the question ask about, which people do we consider, academics, engineers, IT specialists, average people, politicians?)

Similar (closed) questions on

- physics: [what-does-it-take-to-become-a-top-physicist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/what-does-it-take-to-become-a-top-physicist)
- maths:
  [mathematical-canon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164787)
- mathoverflow:
  [how-to-become-a-good-mathematician](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26967)
- stackoverflow:
  [what-are-the-dark-corners-of-vim-your-mom-never-told-you-about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726894/)
- software engineering: [what-should-every-programmer-know](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91350)

There are also questions that did not get closed like [design-patterns-that-every-developer-must-know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247803/design-patterns-that-every-developer-must-know) but in principle stackexchange avoids to have these questions.

---

If the question is, for some reason, not being closed then at least it should be considered to be improved along the lines of the list [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

A good comparison (and contrast) is Gerard het Hooft's [How to become a
GOOD Theoretical Physicist](http://www.goodtheorist.science/) . If the question could be phrased in such a way that it leads to a fine answer like Gerard het Hooft's then the question may be usefull and constructive.

However theoretical physics is a reasonably confined field. Untill a student is starting to do a Phd a lot of the curriculum is pretty much the same or at least there are many resemblences among different programs (you can not say the same for statistics).

- Gerard het Hooft describes this as *"Theoretical Physics is like a sky scraper"* and his webpage is describing all the floors.
- Statistics is much more like a village with lots of different
  buidlings. Even the building materials may be different
  (wood/concrete/metal). A statistician like Edward Tufte specializes in
  data visualisation, a machine learning Guru like Andrew Ng knowns all
  about computer science, and a statistician like Ronald Fisher knows a
  lot about mathematics (and biology). It will be very difficult to shape the question in such a form that it allows clear (conclusive) answers that will resemble something like Gerard's webpage.

The question 'How to become a good <strike>Theoretical</strike> Physicist' would be similarly difficult. It would also be leading to too much divergent possibilities to answer. (I have to think now about one of my instructors for a workgroup seminar in a first year astronomy class at University, answering to a more complicated question something like "Oh, I do not know anything about general relativity, I don't need to")

Answer (score 0):

I edited the question and wrote that I want to delete it because of all the shitstorm and those who want can save the answers before they are gone. But my edit was denied.

Anyway, cynical answers to

What do you consider a person MUST know about statistics and machine learning?

> Nothing. There is no must-know knowledge for 'a person'.
>
> Many people are living happy lives without knowing anything about
>   statistics and/or machine learning.

don't help anyone. I am surprised how little constructive users with this much rep can be. Instead of improving the question or asking someone else to improve it after saying what should be improved he decided to point out such problems in a completely useless and cynical and thus offending answer. Although he denied in the comments beneath his answer that the intent of the post was to point out how bad my question was he wrote here "I have added an answer to your question that may prove my point about the subjectivity and fuzziness of your question. It is too much unclear what goal should be".

Ironically, the question itself was not the problem and led to little discussion if you read the comments on the answers. But so did the whole "it must be closed because subjective thing lead to endless discussions" comments that started a huge discussion.

Anyway, after just seeing that this childish behavior got even positive feedback I delete the whole question. That is too much madness for me.

Comment: I can't delete it at the moment. Maybe because it is on hold. I'll do so as soon as I can.

Comment: You call it childish, but I had not posted my cynical answer untill you started to be so difficult with the criticism to you question, dodging comments (by pointing to other non-closed Qs) instead of showing any movement towards improving it. If you do not make more clear what your question is about or give more detailed guideliness about desired answers (I had asked explicitly what an acceptable answer should entail) then you get what you ask. The cynical comment is my opinion and I should be entitled to this opinion. If you do not like this then do not ask questions that ask for opinions.

Comment: You wrote that what wanted to do with your answer was to point out tat my question is bad. That is not constructive

Comment: Yeah, vote it down. Cross validated appears to basivally ruled by some gathered group. You probably know each other for years and dislike a newbie being honest anout the contradiction in the application of the rules. If you simply like cartoons just say it. If yu really find the answer I quoted helpful I'm out.

Comment: You are seeing too much in my answer. The answer that I posted is how I imagined *my* answer to your question (how I first interpreted it). I understand that this is not what you are probably seeking for. Therefore I did not post such answer but started an enquiry about your question instead. But you did not clarify anything about you question which did not allow me to adjust my answer. So yes I posted the question to prove a point, but it is in order to be constructive. It clarifies how the question is unclear. Instead of complaining about it you could also try to improve the question

Comment: Your point wass correct: I was not specific enough with "a person". But your answer was obviously cynical and thus offensive and not very constructive. We were writing here thhat much about the question. You could have simply mention it and I would have changed it. That simple

Comment: I was among the upvoters, for all three answers.

Comment: So if you enjoy the answers but not the question that makes even less sense to me why you didn't try to imorove my (bad) question

Comment: I am sorry that the discussion developed in such a way that it makes you feel bad about it. But the most important point is that the question does not fit the *format* of this website. It is much less about whether or not the question is getting lots of votes or not. I have pointed out some ideas why the question is a difficult concept here. I have provided by way of example an answer that illustrates difficulties with the question....

Comment: ....It is however now up to you to improve the question or at least respond to it in some way that allows others to help you further with improving the question. We can not know what *you mean* with the question. Defending the question (that it should remain in its current state and dragging all kinds of other old non-closed questions into the equation to prove that point) is not gonna help in this direction. Looking for how to change (explain better the problem behind the question and narrow down the scope), might however (maybe) lead to a solution.

Comment: To be honest I dodn't think I can "save" the question because the question I have is as broad as I asked it.It doesn't nake sense to ask something that broad to many others obviously.But to me the answers were exactly what I was expecting and in fact I enjoy the reading that was inspired by the answer from ooloney.So I personally got what I wanted and I wanted to delete it because the whole discussion was really frustrating to me.But I simply wouldn't know how to edit it so that it is alrigh for cv even if I would want to because by tryung to do so I would try to make up a question I dont have

Comment: To put it short: my question was obviously bad for cv. But for the reasons mentioned I don't know how to improve it. So anyone who wants to can edit however he wants to. But still, me pointing out all the other subjective questions not being closed is a valid argument. It is simply inconsistent to close some questions and other not. Inagine this would be how actual laws would work - some get in prison others not. Of course you would be happy if you are the lucky one. But how would you feel being the unlucky one?

Comment: It is simply natural that everyone wants to be treated fair and wants that rules are applied consistently. A great example are experiments with monkeys that show how universal the need for fairness is. See here https://youtu.be/meiU6TxysCg for a short summary if you wish

Comment: (@SkanderH pinging you here as this also applies to your comment) The least suitable questions for the SE network are frequently highly popular because they attract attention from people who don't normally vote  (they tend to invite speculation and controversy, for example and they're relatively likely to hit the HNQ list gaining votes from people who don't normally read here at all). I am completely sympathetic to the call for consistency (when the parallels are sufficiently clear), but it's not reasonable to expect complete consistency (e.g. site norms evolved a lot in the early years)...ctd

Comment: ctd... If (for example) there have been a couple of thousand questions in a similar vein to this one and say 1,973 were closed, it's not reasonable to point to a couple of dozen open ones (some of which are open for good reason, some not, and some sufficiently close to the borderline that it's not clear what to do with them) and say "look, those ones aren't closed". This is [survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias); look instead at the characteristics of the much larger number of similar posts that were closed; the post currently at issue fits among them very well.

Comment: @igoR you can't delete it now because it's locked, not because it's on hold; locking a controversial post protects it while its status is discussed here (it will stop it getting a lot of bad answers, for example). This is a normal thing to do in this situation.

Comment: @Glen_b: since I am a human being survivorship bias also applies to me. I wouldn't deny that. As I wrote, retrospectivelly, I shulouldn't have asked. But once I asked all the critic started. This "question" begins with the statement I was being flatgery and so on. Thus I wanted to delete the question which did not work either. I won't ask or answer stuff (in near future) at cv anymore. That saves frustration for me and for all of you. Although I had the feeling that there was some discussion initiated by my post that maybe was some benefit but I can't estimate that.

Comment: I just noticed that my post about the useless and cynical answer from Martijn Weterings was downvoted. As a passive member I didn't saw how much madness here is whch was maube because I didn't red the discussions. Unbelievable how far group thinking leads. That is simply to stupd to me. I am defiantly out.

Comment: @igoR87 It's a great pity to me that you say that you intend to leave, although good news that you seem to be still looking at the site. But I think you're over-reacting to what is just disagreement that is all part and parcel of being a forum. Compared with  many sites, CV is civil and courteous and people are taken seriously if (and only if) they have good arguments. Your own language here ("shitstorm", "useless", "cynical") shows that you give as much flak as you get. Default style here is closer to British understatement, although that's not compulsory any more than being British is.

Comment: Downvoting on Meta just means that people disagree with specific content, not at all that your opinion may not have merit or be respected.

Answer (score -6):

Based on the following precedents:

[Is a strong background in maths a total requisite for ML?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40808/is-a-strong-background-in-maths-a-total-requisite-for-ml)

[What math subjects would you suggest to prepare for data mining and machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/what-math-subjects-would-you-suggest-to-prepare-for-data-mining-and-machine-lear?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Having a job in data-mining without a PhD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/having-a-job-in-data-mining-without-a-phd?rq=1)

[What is the difference between data mining, statistics, machine learning and AI?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-statistics-machine-learning-and-ai?rq=1)

[What is the daily job routine of the machine learning scientist?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109210/what-is-the-daily-job-routine-of-the-machine-learning-scientist?rq=1)

The question in the OP should remain open as well.

The above linked questions are not just cases of opinion based questions that slipped through the net. All are highly upvoted, so presumably that's an indication that the community as a whole approves - and isn't SE supposed to be essentially democratic?

Comment: Martijn's answer gets to the heart of the matter with his exposition about good-subjective versus bad-subjective. Right now, the line of reasoning in this Answer is more-or-less "We have *other* subjective questions, so we should also have *this* subjective question." I think this Answer would be stronger if it addressed the problem in a slightly different way: "This question is good-subjective because..."

Comment: Why then do we even have closing options for being opinion based or being too broad? Let's just stop closing questions altogether since we have these other cases that slipped through the net⸮ In the first place, a question should be having value on its own and this should be primarily discussed. Then, when we see it is a gray area we can argue how far it is acceptable and old cases may help to see how the community thinks about this. There are 5 cases presented that remained open. But as statisticians, shouldn't we look also at the rest of the data, all those other questions that got closed?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings the questions I mentioned as examples are not only notable for having remained open despite being opinion based, but also have a very large number of up-votes, so they didn't just slip through the net, clearly the community finds them useful.

Comment: Excatly what I think. I don't argue "there're other stupid questions and thus my stupid question is ok".I find the links of Skaner H. not stupid but helpful and obviously the community does the same as the votes indicate. But now it is almost impossible to tell whether my (subjective) question is one of the good once because adter all this hate probably barely anyone dares to post an answer. Ironically, the only thing that has made my question a discussion was all the questioning whether to close or not to close it. In the post itself there is very little discussion on opinions to the answers.

Comment: That is a fair point. I think it needs some more nuance however. 1) The issue here is not so much about the value of the single questions, but much more about whether these type of questions/discussions should be answered here on stackexchange (not a place for a poll that invites lots of opinions) instead of some other place like usenet or some other forum. 2) Voting here means in the first place that somebody voted, it is not to be directly translated to a single dimensional usefullness scale. For that, there is too much diversity in voting, and facebook-style popularity voting is among it.

Comment: @igoR87 The answers all take different angles for what is understood by 'people' (people that are consultants, people getting consultants, people looking for a stats job) it is too much open in that way.

Comment: @igoR87 if that is not the argument that you are making then you should not have referred to those cases.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Retrospectively, I wouldn't have posted the question another time. I was thinking there will be some critic but I didn't see so much comming. But as you say, of course stackexchange must not become completely some opinion website. I would definitely hate that, too. So I understand the arguments for closing.

Comment: If the OP of that question is not enough happy with one of the current answers, which are all great, then it is not a good question for stackexchange format. This format is in principle that a single answer should be enough. Straightforward question, not something that turns into a 'mess' (no matter how many votes it gets). How much more answer does the OP need? Or how should they be improved to be acceptable?

Comment: @martijn-weterings: you are right about my first link to the cartoon. But the second link I posted was https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means/133694?r=SearchResults#133694 which I find an relevant and acceptable question. At the same time the difference between the accepted answer and the most up-voted show that even in such cases there is some degree of subjective judgement since people vote better looking/ easier explained answers higher.

Comment: "This format is in principle that a single answer should be enough". Yes, but... Talking about the last link I provided about k means it actually would answer the question to write the mathimatical proof and show the results of some simulation that show the drawbacks in only a few sentences.But of course people await an answer which explains the topic more easily and vividly. And if you have a look at the link the answers are really didactically great.Thus it is always quite subjective waht a good answer is or how many answers are needed (which depends on knowledge the reader has)

Comment: @igoR87 you are right that it is a gray area when it is not a hard science. Also, even in mathematics, you can have multiple answers with different approaches and providing a different level of intuition. It is true that there is never truly a single answer possible and multiple approaches can reach the same goal and from a didactical point of view it would be even good to have multiple questions. However, the multiple questions that would be answered to polls like "what do you think..." are of a different kind (not like multiple ways to reach the same goal, instead more like different goals).

Comment: @igoR87 I must not add a disclaimer that I am in principle not entirely against the question that you asked. If the question leads to an answer like Gerard het Hooft's [How to become a
GOOD Theoretical Physicist](http://www.goodtheorist.science/) then it would be great. However your question is currently phrased in a very ambiguous and sujective way....

Comment: @Martijn Weterings: Yes I agree with that. I want to add to the previous sentence "If the OP of that question is not enough happy with one of the current answers...". I am actually really happy! I'll wait for some more before accepting one. Here your critic proves to be true because it will be a subjective judgment me deciding what to accept. That is why I maybe rather leave it open and ordered by votes.

Comment: ....Gerard's question (and answer) is more specific, it relates to 1) a clear *problem case* 'the many people that ask him how to become theoretical physicist, or the many people that suggest they found some new theory' (this is different than the problem case 'I am looking for inspiration' it makes the possibilities to answer too much variable) 2) It is about a clear field *theoretical* physics. Your question is about Statistics AND machine learning. That is an enormously broad field. This is potentially gonna generate a different answer (opinion) from each different user on this website.

Comment: Again, I agree with that. There are going to be many different opinions. And it is important that stackexchange doesn't become subjective as a whole. But to me the great answers and the clarification I gained by the answers make my question one of the good subjective ones. The number of up-votes for the answers seem to indicate that this could be true for others, too. In that sense I find it a pity that at the same time my question got downvoted.

Comment: @Syxorax: "This question is good-subjective because...". I did that in the edit. I wrote "... the answers to my question can give a feeling for what needs to be known to be a statistician to many people that are at the beginning of their career...."

Comment: @Martijn Weterings: "However your question is currently phrased in a very ambiguous and sujective way". I was afraid this would be the case. This can be partly due to my english. I don't know why there is no-one editing it more. Maybe because the question was questioned so mhch I don't know

Comment: @igoR87 I have added an answer to your question that may prove my point about the subjectivity and fuzziness of your question. It is too much unclear what goal should be reached with your question, and what direction is necessary. This is also why nobody is correcting your question (because we do not know what you wanted to get out of it).

Comment: That some other opinion-based question felt to be similar is not closed is not a reason to keep this open; it may sometimes be a reason to close the other one.

Comment: @Martijn Weterings: I saw your cynical answer. To me you could rather edit the question than post a quite useless answer. All you wanted to point out me being not precise enough that it is not about "a person" but "what must a statician know". Posting an answer for that doesn't make sense and actually also validtes rules since it is not a serious answer.

Comment: How about precedents where similar questions **did** get closed? I suspect there are multiple...

Comment: @Glen_b Yes but the similar questions I linked to are all highly upvoted questions, so clearly the community as a whole approves of them.

Comment: @Jan  Many hundreds of posts more or less like the ones claimed to be similar have been closed. Between the moderators and the ordinary users with sufficient reputation to do so, we close quite a few every week. [That there's perhaps a few dozen - some deliberately grandfathered for historical reasons - still around doesn't indicate that the norm is to keep them open. They're nearly always closed.]

Comment: @Glen_b: I have no understanding why someone brings this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151216/are-we-exaggerating-importance-of-model-assumption-and-evaluation-in-an-era-when post back to top on cv after arguing that subjective question don't belong on cv. The question *could* be objective if it were about the need of assumptions alone but the aspect layman vs. statician opens a subjective area what one can see in the answers. Aspects like "I work with some doctors who are reasonably statistically competent..." are mainly subjective experience (from your answer)